# Select all rows from joined table as colums

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi i have a problem selecting rows from database tables.

**Table A**

```
Id, name
```

**Table B**

```
Id, playingdate, points
```

Table a and b are linked with the is such as `a.id = b.id`

Data for table a

```
1, john
2, tim
```

Data for table b

```
1, 20170101, 3455
1, 20170108, 4532
2, 20170101, 5666
2, 20170108, 4768
```

So i want to return

```
John, 3455, 4532
Tim, 5666, 4768
```

How do i buid the sql select ?

Comment: If the number of playing dates be variable/unknown, then you would need some dynamic SQL to solve this.  Have you tried something yet?

Comment: You can't return a variable number of columns with "vanilla" SQL, you'd have to return two return a row for each of those numbers, and join in a list in your application.

Comment: select name,points from table a,table b where a.id=b.id;

Comment: You might want to look at your design, maybe this would be easier to accomplish in code instead of using a sql query?

Comment: this is possible with storedprocedure

Comment: Will `playingdate` column have only two values `20170101` and `20170108`?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why need this, as the points might be very long:

```
SELECT A.name, group_concat(B.points)
FROM A
JOIN B ON A.id = B.id
GROUP BY A.name
```

AS you also asked it is in columns, then it is even rarely used. However if the column is fixed as: name, 20170101, 20170108, Then the SQL will be:

```
SELECT 
  A.name,
  ifnull(B1.points,0) AS '20170101',
  ifnull(B2.points,0) AS '20170108'
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B AS B1 ON A.id = B1.id AND B1.playingdate = 20170101
LEFT JOIN B AS B2 ON A.id = B2.id AND B2.playingdate = 20170108
```

Comment: ifnull or isnull?

Comment: ifnull(col, null_replacement) vs isnull(col) -- they are different

Answer (score 0):

First group_concat and concat with name on table A and B:

```
 SELECT concat(A.name, ',' , group_concat(B.points)) as  name_points
        FROM A
        left outer join B ON A.id = B.id
        GROUP BY A.id
```

---

```
SELECT A.name, group_concat(B.points) as  points
        FROM A
        left outer join B ON A.id = B.id
        GROUP BY A.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a working solution for your query....let me know if you have any issue to get it...

```
set @row1 := 0;
set @row2 := 0;
select a.id,a.name,c.p1,c.p2
from a 
inner join 
(
select b1.id,b1.p1,b2.p2
from 
    (   
    select @row1 := @row1 +1 as r1,b.id ,b.points as p1
    from b
    group by id 
    )b1
inner join 
    (
    select @row2 := @row2 +1 as r2,b.points as p2
    from b
    )b2
on b1.r1+1 = b2.r2
)c on a.id = c.id
```